# Thoughts on increasing flavor of blueberry wine

Tags: wine

I just sampled my blueberry wine that's been aging for a couple of months now in the carboy.  A generous description would be "light bodied."  There's not a lot of flavor.  Alcohol, yes, but just a hint of blueberry.  Any thoughts on what one could do to increase the flavor, or is that what blueberry wine is supposed to taste like?

I plan to make a dessert wine out of it.  Will adding sugar later help the flavor?

Comment: http://www.midwestsupplies.com/blueberry-extract-4-oz.html

Comment: How did you make this blueberry wine?

Answer (score 2):

Add blueberry honey. It's a great way to reintroduce the floral blueberry flavors and aromas that often get lost during fermentation. The added sweetness is likely to improve your perception of "fruitiness" as well.

Comment: I just bought some organic blueberry honey, and it tastes exactly like....honey.  I can't taste or smell any floral notes or blueberry anything.  A shame, since it was rather pricey.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's mostly in the aroma, and the blueberry honey I've used has a pretty intense blueberry character. The brand I use is Dutch Gold. Hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Early on, I made a number of fruit wines and I found my initial attempts produced a very thin, light bodied wine with marginal flavors similar to the experiences you're having with your batch of blueberry wine.  It takes a significant amount of ripe fruit to produce strong flavors in fruit wines.
Also, yeast selection is important, as well as keeping your ABV 12% or a bit less, keeping the alcohol from masking the fruit.
You may wish to experiment with one gallon batches, working to get your proportions correct to give you results you want.
Another option you have is to blend some of your blueberry wine with another red wine.  I have had good success blending blackberry with Cabernet Sauvignon. Blueberry has been blended with Pinot Noir.

Comment: Since I already have the wine, I might try the Pinot.  Have you ever tried using any extracts to boost the flavor?

Comment: Yes, I tried a organic blackberry favoring, figure that would be good, right? Tasted like a bottle of Jolly Rancher candy ;-)  Blending probably your best bet, chalk it up to experience.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts (YMMV) would be:

- Yeast, look for one which says on the packet ([web site](http://vintnersharvest.com/pages/using-fruit-wine-bases) etc) that it is good with fruit/floral wines, [e.g.](http://vintnersharvest.com/collections/wine-yeasts/products/vintners-harvest-wine-yeast-r56),
- Make sure you don't let the wine oxidise (don't over handle it, use a [Campden tablet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campden_tablet), etc)
- You may want to add some tannins(you can buy this in powered form), to hold the body together.

I have tried some very nice blueberry ports, so if you have some neutral spirit handy, you could add that in part way through a brew, and see what you get.

You could also try [freeze concentrating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applejack_%28beverage%29) your current batch. Which will bump up the flavour, alcohol, and sugars.